# Angular2 EXCEPTION: Does not support more than 9 expressions

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding

I am writing an Angular 2 application, And i can't understand why Angular can not support more than 9 expressions.[image: the console show me this error]

Comment: I'm curious about what the expression looks lik

Comment: Not sure, but if you look at your html having hundreds of object properties... I think I understand why they didnt bother to have more at least. You can create an object in the controller and pass that instead creating your object in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Angular2 does not support more than 9 expressions in the same HTML element. Try to move the bindings to another element.